# intellij taking file path incorrectly

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty-9

Intellij taking file path incorrectly: D:\jetty-distribution-9.2.1.v20140609\?D:\images\a.txt

When I give files like

File file = new File("‪D:\images\1.txt");
  System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

The output is
D:\jetty-distribution-9.2.1.v20140609\?D:\images\1.txt

It is considering the file path along with server bin

Where do i need to change the setting to detect the absolute path in intelij.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslashes `\\` to escape the `\`, then it will work.

```
File file = new File("‪D:\\images\\1.txt"); System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: i have tried in that way it didn't work.. still giving the same path